# Css background color change based on if a div is being show, or not

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am looking for a way to change the background color of the page depending on which one of two divs is being shown on the page. This would be by ID. Sometimes `div id="a"` will be show on the page. Sometimes `div id="b"` will be shown instead. A will not exist at all in when B is shown. A simply would not be rendered, it would NOT just be hidden or display none but rather would not show up at all.

How can I do this?

Comment: can you use javascript?

Comment: yes I can use js

Comment: @DCR is right. Use javaScript

Comment: alright love it, any chance someone could point me in the right direction of what I am looking for on how to do that?

Comment: Can you share, and show, the representative html you’re working with in in order that we can more easily help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
window.onload = function(){
var ab =document.getElementById('a')
var bod = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]

if(ab == null){
    
    bod.style.background='green'
}else{
   bod.style.background='blue'
   
}}
```

```html
<body>

<div id = 'b'>this is B</div>

</body>
```

Comment: thanks very much. Is there an advantage to this version over the answer below or just a different way?

Comment: you want to use the window.onload statement.  If you try to access an element before the DOM is loaded it won't work

Comment: yea I had to delay this in trying it because it was loading to quickly. I am see this is set to taget the background color of the div a or b, but it should be targeting the backgound of the body of the page or a the main wrapper div. What do I need to alter to accomplish that?"

Answer (score 0):

You can try this using `jQuery` :

```js
var idOfDiv = $('body > div').attr('id');
if ((idOfDiv) === "a") {
  $('body').css('background-color', 'green');
}
else if ((idOfDiv) === "b") {
  $('body').css('background-color', 'blue');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Change the id from a to b OR b to a
<div id="a">
  Lorem Ipsum
</div>
```

[JS Fiddle using jQuery](https://jsfiddle.net/36d5mxLf/)

or if you pure JS, the you can do this :

```js
var idOfDiv = document.getElementById('a');
if (idOfDiv === null) {
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = 'blue';
} else {
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = 'green';
}
```

```html
/*Change the id from a to b OR b to a*/
<div id="a">
  Lorem Ipsum
</div>
```

[JS Fiddle using pure JavaScript](https://jsfiddle.net/msye7jqw/)

Comment: Thanks so much this is great. And if I wanted to change the target of the color to a div instead of changing the background I presume I would change - ` $('body').css('background-color', 'blue');` to something like  `$('#mydivid').css('background-color', 'blue');`

Answer (score 0):

I am big surprised as every one is answering with js. But if you have two ids fixed with a and b name for divs,then you can achieve this in css file as

```
div#a{
background-color:red;
}
div#b{
background-color:red;
}
```